# How to prevent origin server IP address behind CDN from exposed, like Cloudflare?

Tags: security, webserver, cdn, cloudflare

I use Cloudflare/Google Cloud Platform as CDN, how to hide my server IP from detection via scanners?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some methods which can help your server from detection, such as IP whitelist, hostname/port change, OpenSSL/SNI patch, website/backend faking, header/client certificate authorization, etc.

In short: **Think like a scanner, and you will be fine.**

I also publish this answer in [my blog](https://blog.sion.moe/methods-to-prevent-leaking-websites-origin-server-ip-behind-cdn/), check if you are interested.

Before start detailing, if you need to protect your server completely, it is **far from enough** by doing things I introduce here. **Security follows the *[Liebig's barrel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liebig%27s_law_of_the_minimum#Liebig%27s_barrel)***; any minor inattention will cause an unpredictable consequence. In short, **you need in charge of your security**. The only thing I wrote here is about how to **prevent IP leak from the webserver**. If there is a neglected place, like design error in the application which causes the IP leak, this won't help.

In general, the way to find your original node is **scanning every possible IP by requesting like regular user, and find target by filtering the results**. In most situation, you can prevent them by setting IP whitelist. But it depends. You may probably don't know the IP that CDN nodes used for requesting your original server, or they're changing. Use this policy may likely cause service interruption.

## Outline

- IP Whitelist
- Change hostname/listen port
- Prevent certification leak from aimless batch scan

  - Domain info on original server would not be inputted the database based on this
  - If possible, change the port the webserver listened to
- Give false information by feigning as other real-existing websites/CDN nodes
- Prevent unauthorized access by feigning as other self-handcrafting websites/returning null

  - Needs to cooperate with other regulations that the CDN provided
  - Client certificate authentication is also an uncommon way
- Conclusion

If you are confused, you can **check the flow chart** in the conclusion first, then continue reading.

## Strategies

Assuming Debian/Ubuntu as OS, and Nginx as web server.

### IP Whitelist

In fact, the most direct, efficient method to prevent original server IP leak is setting IP whitelist. *If you can do so, you should do so.* However, do remember the things:

1. If CDN provider does not provide IP list in use, *do not use this strategy, or service interruption may occur*;
2. If using HTTPS as scheme while requesting the original server, you should use iptables instead of Nginx's *[build-in access module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html)*, or the searcher still can find your server by detecting certificate's SNI;
3. Simply only applying IP whitelist if using Cloudflare as CDN *may give a chance for searcher to bypass Cloudflare's protection* and make them find your original IP address.

   - If worth, searcher can upload script to [Cloudflare Worker](https://workers.cloudflare.com) and scan your IP by Cloudflare's IPs, which can bypass your IP whitelist setting;
   - Enabling [Custom Hostname (Enterprise feature)](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217371987-Managing-Custom-Hostnames-SSL-for-SaaS-) or [Authenticated Origin Pulls/Client Certificate Authentication](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204899617-Authenticated-Origin-Pulls#section5) **"correctly"** can avoid this issue.

If you are using iptables, do remember to install iptables-persistent, or you may lose your filter rules if reboot:

```
apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

Example of dropping requests from not whitelisted IPs:
[image]

### Change hostname/listen port

Generally, aimed scanners will scan all IPs with standard ports(http/80, https/443) with your website's exposed domain/hostname. So if you can change them, it will usually be okay.

[image]
*You can customize your origin hostname/domain for CDN nodes to request, to prevent searcher detect your origin server IP via hostname*

[image]
*Few CDN providers support customize port for requests to origin server*

However, if you somehow let the searcher know your hostname, or IP ranges you use, your origin server has the risk to be exposed. So, do care.

### Prevent Certificate SNI Leak patch

The intention of rejecting SSL handshake is preventing certificate's SNI info leak (or can be easily considered as domain info) from the aimless batch scan. The searcher can build a website-IP relation database based on this for quick search in the feature after the aimless batch scan.

Domain information is included in certificate, which can be for acknowledging what websites are running (Though they may not actually run):
[image]

If your Nginx version is higher than 1.19.4, you can simply use the [ssl_reject_handshake](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_reject_handshake) feature to prevent SNI info leak. Otherwise, you will need to apply the [strict-sni patch](https://git.hakase.app/Hakase/openssl-patch).

*N.B. This measure only works if you want to use **HTTPS** as the scheme for CDN nodes requesting the original server. If you only tend to use **HTTP** as the scheme for the requests, you can simply `return 444;` in default server block and there is no need to continue reading or just skim this part.*

#### Configuration of ssl_reject_handshake (Nginx ≥ 1.19.4)

Two parts are involved in the configuration of the ssl_reject_handshake, default block, and normal block:

```
server { # Default block returns null for SSL requests with wrong hostname
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_reject_handshake on;
}

server { # With the correct hostname, server will process requests
    listen  443 ssl;
    server_name test.com;
    ssl_certificate test.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key test.com.key;
}
```

If using Nginx 1.19.3 or below, you can use [sni-strict patch](https://git.hakase.app/Hakase/openssl-patch) instead. This patch is developed by [Hakase](https://haka.se/), which can [return a true empty response](https://github.com/hakasenyang/openssl-patch/issues/7#issuecomment-428252380) for invalid requests if your Nginx version is before 1.19.4.

#### Steps for installing sni-strict patch (Nginx ≤ 1.19.3)

First, install necessary packages:

```
apt-get install git curl gcc libpcre3-dev software-properties-common \
build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libxslt1-dev libgd-dev libperl-dev
```

Then, download OpenSSL version you need in [release page](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases).

Download repository [openssl-patch](https://git.hakase.app/Hakase/openssl-patch):

```
git clone https://git.hakase.app/Hakase/openssl-patch.git
```

Based on OpenSSL version you choose before, switch directory to the OpenSSL code's directory, and then patch OpenSSL with the related patch:

```
cd openssl
patch -p1 < ../openssl-patch/openssl-equal-1.1.1d_ciphers.patch
```

> [Note](https://github.com/hakasenyang/openssl-patch/issues/42#issuecomment-694900591) from developer: OpenSSL 3.x has many API changes, and this patch
> is no longer useful. (Chacha20 and Equal Preference patch) It is
> recommended using version 1.1.x whenever possible.

Download [Nginx package](https://nginx.org/en/download.html) with the version you need.
Decompress Nginx package, switch directory into Nginx, and patch Nginx:

```
cd nginx/
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hakasenyang/openssl-patch/master/nginx_strict-sni_1.15.10.patch | patch -p1
```

Specify OpenSSL directory in configure arguments:

```
./configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl=/root/openssl
```

*N.B. In actual practice, these arguments are far from making website work as expection, you need to plus what you need as what you want. For example, if you want your website deployed with http/2 protocol, argument `--with-http_v2_module` needs to be added, or module won't be built.*

If you tend to feign your server as other real-existing websites for **aimless batch scan, intend to give scanner false information instead of null**, you can also plus extra arguments here:

```
./configure --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl=/root/openssl
```

*P.S. This part is referring to "give false information by feigning as other real-existing websites/CDN nodes" in outline, which is only for giving false information to **aimless scanner**, and this is **hard to work greatly** for **aimed scan**. If you only want to show fake website to unauthorized clients, like handcrafting fake website, making reserved proxy, etc. (and return null information to aimless scanner), you should skip this part, or only add these arguments for advance.*

After configuration, build and install Nginx.
`make && make install`
And installation is finished.
To be convenient, I prefer to do these also after then:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ /usr/share/nginx
ln -s /usr/share/nginx/sbin/nginx /usr/sbin

cat > /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service <<-EOF
[Unit]
Description=The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

systemctl enable nginx
```

#### Configuration of sni-strict patch (Nginx ≤ 1.19.3)

The configuration is similar to [ssl_reject_handshake](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_reject_handshake). There're 3 elements needs to be configured:

1. Control options
2. Fake(default) server block
3. Normal server blocks

```
http {
    # control options
    strict_sni on;
    strict_sni_header on;

    # fake server block
    server {
        server_name  localhost;
        listen       80;
        listen       443 ssl default_server; # "default_server" is necessary
        ssl_certificate /root/cert.crt; # Can be any certificate here
        ssl_certificate_key /root/cert.key; # Can be any certificate here

        location / {
            return 444;
        }
    }

    # normal server blocks
    server {
        server_name  normal_domain.tld;
        listen       80;
        listen       443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /root/cert.crt; # Your real certificate here
        ssl_certificate_key /root/cert/cert.key; # Your real certificate here

        location / {
            echo "Hello World!";   
        }
    }
}
```

Now, **aimless** batch scanner cannot know what website you are running on this server, except situation that they already know and scan your server with hostname, which is called **aimed** scanner.

*P.S. `return 444;` means return literally nothing when it comes to HTTP (not HTTPS) requests. If strict-sni not patched, certification information will still be returned while client trying to establish TLS connection.*

*N.B. After `strict_sni on;` be set, CDN nodes needs request with SNI or will encounter failure. See as: [proxy_ssl_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_name).*

#### Results

You can see certificate information is hidden when option turned on.
Before:

```
curl -v -k https://35.186.1.1
* Rebuilt URL to: https://35.186.1.1/
*   Trying 35.186.1.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 35.186.1.1 (35.186.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=normal_domain.tld
*  start date: Nov 15 05:41:39 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 14 05:41:39 2020 GMT
*  issuer: CN=normal_domain.tld
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 35.186.1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 35.186.1.1 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

After:

```
curl -v -k https://35.186.1.1
* Rebuilt URL to: https://35.186.1.1/
*   Trying 35.186.1.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 35.186.1.1 (35.186.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14094458:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 unrecognized name
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14094458:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 unrecognized name
```

In case, you should know certification information will still be returned while requesting with target hostname. Even you have configured client check rules(like: HTTP header check, etc.) after then. This is also why this can only prevent aimless scan: it only works when attacker doesn't know what website you are running on this server. To cope with aimed scan, as original node, I highly recommend changing hostname, if possible.

Request with the wrong hostname: (Certificate info is not returned if the hostname is wrong)

```
curl -v -k --resolve wrong_domain.tld:443:35.186.1.1 https://wrong_domain.tld
* Added wrong_domain.tld:443:35.186.1.1 to DNS cache
* Rebuilt URL to: https://wrong_domain.tld/
* Hostname wrong_domain.tld was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 35.186.1.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to wrong_domain.tld (35.186.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14094458:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 unrecognized name
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14094458:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 unrecognized name
```

Request with the right hostname: (Only if the hostname is correct, the certificate info will be returned)

```
curl -v -k --resolve normal_domain.tld:443:35.186.1.1 https://normal_domain.tld
* Added normal_domain.tld:443:35.186.1.1 to DNS cache
* Rebuilt URL to: https://normal_domain.tld/
* Hostname normal_domain.tld was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 35.186.1.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to normal_domain.tld (35.186.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=normal_domain.tld
*  start date: Nov 15 05:41:39 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 14 05:41:39 2020 GMT
*  issuer: CN=normal_domain.tld
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: normal_domain.tld
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.17.5
< Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2019 05:53:19 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Connection: keep-alive
* Connection #0 to host normal_domain.tld left intact
```

*P.S. If you know IP range that known aimless scanners used, you can use iptables to block them also, as another minor safe protect measure. Such as IP range of Censys's scanner listed below:*

```
74.120.14.0/24
192.35.168.0/23
162.142.125.0/24
167.248.133.0/24
```

### Give false information by feigning as other real-existing websites/CDN nodes

With this strategy, you can give some false information to the aimless scanner to let them build a database with false information. You may want to impose the scanner that your server is a CDN server; you may also want to combine your real site inside to confuse the aimed scanner to make it can not tell the server it detects is the original server or the CDN node, etc.
Personally, I am not willing to use this strategy, because it needs me to consider many factors, like which IDC provider will the real CDN node use (and host my website on the same IDC), the [ASN (Autonomous System Number)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_Number) its IP uses, the ports it opens, the HTTP header info added by CDN, etc., to make sure searcher will feel confused. This is very plaguy.

*N.B. You should set HTTPS as the only scheme for CDN nodes to request your origin server if possible. **Otherwise, you need to care if the behavior on HTTP port.** Such as the target server/website you want to feign always redirect http/80 requests to https/443 port, but you forget to turn requests to your website on http/80 port to https/443.*

*P.S. In fact, it is not a bad but not good decision to feign the server as Cloudflare's CDN server. Because even though we can find [Cloudflare's IP range](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/) on official website, which makes you may consider that Cloudflare will only use these IP for CDN nodes, there are **some currently-existing servers are actually running Cloudflare's CDN node application, whose IPs are not included inside the IP list** (or they are running the forward-proxy like what I will write next). Once upon a time, I ran a scan and found some servers without using Cloudflare's IPs which are doing the thing above. Thus, feigning as Cloudflare's CDN server is a thing: you would not actually need to have/use Cloudflare's IPs.

However, It is also not a thing, because you must use your own-created(includes both the self-signed or the not) certificate for your real website. As we know, most Cloudflare users use the certificate signed by Cloudflare. If you do want to feign your server as Cloudflare's, do consider for what purpose you want to do this.*

#### Configuration

P.S. If you don't know how to install ngx_stream_module, check the steps for installing sni-strict patch for Nginx 1.19.3 or below. The relative is there.
There are 3 main points in the configuration:

1. Feigning/default block for the port http/80 in the http block;
2. Feigning/default block for the port https/443 in the stream block;
3. The block to route your real domain/website to the backend.

Example of the configuration:

```
load_module "modules/ngx_stream_module.so";

http{ # Design the http block by yourself
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://104.27.184.146:80; # Feign as Cloudflare's CDN node
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name yourwebsite.com; # If you set https as the only scheme for CDN nodes requesting your origin server, you should not configure the block of your real website in the http{} block, aka here (except that the listen address is "localhost" instead of the public network IP)
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; # Your backend
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}

stream{
    map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
        yourwebsite.com website-upstream; # Your real website's route
        default cloudflare; # Default route
    }
    upstream cloudflare {
        server 104.27.184.146:443; # Cloudflare IP
    }
    upstream website-upstream {server 127.0.0.1:8080;} # Your real website's backend
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $name;
        proxy_ssl_name $ssl_preread_server_name;
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
```

#### Result

It will return the content with the real-existing certificate of other websites:

```
curl -I -v --resolve www.cloudflare.com:443:127.0.0.1 https://www.cloudflare.com/

* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55f3f0ae0f50)
* Added www.cloudflare.com:443:127.0.0.1 to DNS cache
* Hostname www.cloudflare.com was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55f3f0ae0f50)
* Connected to www.cloudflare.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; jurisdictionC=US; jurisdictionST=Delaware; serialNumber=4710875; C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=cloudflare.com
*  start date: Oct 30 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Nov  3 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.cloudflare.com" matched cert's "www.cloudflare.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert ECC Extended Validation Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55f3f0ae0f50)
> HEAD / HTTP/2
> Host: www.cloudflare.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 256)!
< HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
< date: Tue, 06 Oct 2020 06:26:50 GMT
* Connection #0 to host www.cloudflare.com left intact
```

*(Succeed to feign as the real website, some results are omitted)*

### Prevent unauthorized access by feigning as other self-handcrafting websites/returning null

Before starting this section, you should know this tactic can only be used while CDN nodes can return something different from normal user. Here is an example:
[image]
*HTTP header settings for requesting origin server in GCP*
**HTTP header check** is a common way to authorize whether the request is from CDN.

*P.S. GCP(Google Cloud Platform)'s HTTP Load balancing service provide an option to set the request headers that GCP CDN nodes should provide while origin servers receiving the data from GCP CDN nodes[^1]. This makes the origin server can know the CDN nodes requests from the normal/spiteful clients.*

[^1]: *Though GCP load balancing/CDN service only accept GCP VM instances as backends, the mechanism is the same.*

*P.S. In some products, some engineers would like to add some header while requesting the origin server for debug, but not as a feature, which means it won't appear in the document of their products (such as CDN.net), the customer service staff are not acknowledged also. If you want discover there's an special header included in the header or not within the CDN product you use, write a simple script to dump all headers you received will be a good choice. This won't be detailed here.*

The configuration is literate, no need to explain.

Configuration if you want to return null:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  yourweb.site;

    if ($http_auth_tag != "here_is_the_credential") {
        return 444;
    }
    location / {
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Configuration if you want to return fake website/backend:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourweb.site;

    if ($http_auth_tag != "here_is_the_credential") {
        return @fake;
    }
    location / {
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
    location @fake {
        root /var/www/fakesite/; # Highly recommend to build a hand-crafting fake website by yourself
    }
}
```

*P.S. If you tend to configure these in https/443 port, I recommend you to self-sign certificate with **unknown domain**. Using real certificate with **exposed domain** may let scanner find your origin server easily. Nginx **allows you to use certificate without matching SNI info with server_name**.*
*N.B. Some may consider using real certificate with the subdomain of the exposed domain, and most probably use Let's Encrypt to get free certificates. It would be best if you cared about the [Certificate Transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Transparency), which can tell what certificates you have within the specific domain. **Especially, Let's Encrypt submits all certificates it issues to CT logs.** (Reference: [Original](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/ct-logs/), [Archive.ph](https://archive.ph/KVWvs#selection-437.0-437.59))*
*If you want to see whether your certificate is logged into the CT log, you can visit [crt.sh](https://crt.sh).*
*If you cannot tell whether CA you want to apply for the certificate submits all certificates it issues to CT logs, you'd better self-sign certificate.*

The self-sign commands are below:

```
cat > csrconfig.txt <<-EOF
[ req ]
default_md=sha256
prompt=no
req_extensions=req_ext
distinguished_name=req_distinguished_name
[ req_distinguished_name ]
commonName=yeet.com
countryName=SG
[ req_ext ]
keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage=critical,serverAuth,clientAuth
subjectAltName=@alt_names
[ alt_names ]
DNS.0=yeet.com
EOF

cat > certconfig.txt <<-EOF
[ req ]
default_md=sha256
prompt=no
req_extensions=req_ext
distinguished_name=req_distinguished_name
[ req_distinguished_name ]
commonName=yeet.com
countryName=SG
[ req_ext ]
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer
keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage=critical,serverAuth,clientAuth
subjectAltName=@alt_names
[ alt_names ]
DNS.0=yeet.com
EOF

openssl genpkey -outform PEM -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out cert.key
openssl req -new -nodes -key cert.key -config csrconfig.txt -out cert.csr
openssl req -x509 -nodes -in cert.csr -days 365 -key cert.key -config certconfig.txt -extensions req_ext -out cert.pem
```

*Considering some readers may use the commands I wrote above to generate CSR file, which can be used to apply for the real certificate, I reserve the field countryName (some CA needs this field exists while receiving CSR file). If you don't need it, you can simply delete it.*

*N.B. Self-sign certificate may rise risk of the [MITM (man-in-the-middle attack)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), unless the underlying facilities are credible, or CDN provider does support requests with provided client certificate, aka [Authenticated Origin Pulls](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204899617-Authenticated-Origin-Pulls#section5) in Cloudflare.*
[image]
*Enable "Authenticated Origin Pulls" in Cloudflare*

**Client Certificates check** is also the way to authorize whether the request is from CDN nodes. Only seldom CDN providers support requesting with the client certificate. Whatever which provider has this feature, the configuration on your sever are likely. Here's the example:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl_certificate cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key cert.key;

    server_name yourdomain.com;

    ssl_client_certificate cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    error_page 495 496 = @444; # For specifying the return instead of giving the default return while the error is related to the client certificate auth error

    location @444 {return 444;}

    location / {
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

*It will return null while facing the [client certificate errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#errors)*

*P.S. Feigning as other websites/backends is also possible, just simply imitate the one in the "HTTP header check" part.*
*N.B. Whatever what method you want to use, do care the default return. Make the default return same as the return if the requests are invalid.*

Make the default return as null as the return for invalid requests:

```
server {
    listen 80  default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/cert.key;

    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        return 444;
    }
}
```

### Rusult

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:80
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

curl -k https://127.0.0.1:443   
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
```

### Conclusion

In simple, to protect your origin server IP from detection, you can:

1. Set IP whitelist if possible
2. Change the hostname of your website on your origin server if possible/Change the listen port if possible
3. Set default return for unmatched hostname
4. Set authorization method for matched hostname
5. Think if you are scanner itself, how will you think about the server behavior

The whole process can be roughly drawn like this:
[image]